# How to change theme in Angular 2 using NgClass directive using two different components ?

Tags: angular

I'm trying to build a theme feature in my Angular 2 project. But facing some problems. Let me first share the code snippet -

results.component.html

```
<div class="row" [ngClass]="themeService.themeClass" class="theme-content">
    <div *ngFor="let item of items$|async" class="result">
        <div class="title">
            <a class="title-pointer" href="{{item.link}}">{{item.title}}</a>
        </div>
        <div class="link">
            <p class="theme-link">{{item.link}}</p>
        </div>
        <div class="description">
            <p class="theme-description">{{item.pubDate|date:'MMMM d, yyyy'}} - {{item.description}}</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

theme.component.html

```
<button type="button" (click)="themeService.themeClass='dark'">Dark Theme</button>
<button type="button" (click)="themeService.themeClass='default'">Default Theme</button>
```

theme.service.ts

```
export class ThemeService {

  public themeClass: string = 'default';

  constructor() { }

}
```

theme.component.scss

```
.theme-content.dark {
    *{
        background-color: #000000;
    }

    .title-pointer {
        font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
        font-size: 12px;
    }
}
```

theme.component.ts

```
export class ThemeComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(
    public themeService: ThemeService
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

As you can see there are two different components : In results component, results are being fetched. In theme component, it will work to change theme dynamically. But I don't know why it is giving me error ? How should I fix this so that, theme feature should work with result's component ?

Comment: If it's giving you an error, then reading it is the first step. You didn't post it, so we can't help you to read it. But anyway, the CSS rules of a component apply to that component, not to others.

Comment: But what is exactly the error?